# How to add extra property to the class in c# during using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes

I would like to extend my class which was generated by EF from database.
I tried to do it using partial class:

```
public partial class Users
{    
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; } = false;       
}
```

I would like to populate my list of Users from database and by default set my extra property `IsOnline` to `false` - later this value will be changed.

The error occured when i tried to download data from DbSet. Something like:

> Invalid column name "IsOnline".

Comment: Please check this post in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378720/how-to-add-new-entity-properties-in-entity-framework-without-changing-database-m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [NotMapped](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) attribute on your property to flag your property as not used with entity framework

```
public partial class Users
{    
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsOnline { get; set; } //by default a boolean property is always false    
}
```